# How to check if the source code has been modified ? (Java)

Tags: java, open-source

I am writing a Java application which will communicate with a remote server to send and receive files (users will have to login first). The source code will be open for public review.

To ensure a conflict-free user experience, the server should only accepts connections from clients which do not run an altered version of the original program.

How can I check that the binary files have not been changed ? For example, send some hash of the running executable (or even the executable itself) and the server will then see if it matches what it should be.

I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500154/how-to-verify-from-server-that-client-code-hasnt-been-modified) but I think in 4 years things must have changed a little bit.

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500154/how-to-verify-from-server-that-client-code-hasnt-been-modified - You say you saw this question and that things have changed, but this is still valid.

Comment: I said things must have changed, because since 2011 no new reply has been posted. So things may or may not have changed.

Comment: Things have not changed.

Comment: So what happens when a client captures your validation hash and uses it in subsequent spoofed requests?  What exactly do you need to validate here?  If you're trying to authenticate/authorize users, there are already ways of doing that and you really shouldn't be inventing your own.

Comment: As @mikeb said, apparently things have not changed, so upon a capture of the hash it is very well possible to spoof future requests.
You mean I should use existing authentication methods instead of reinventing the wheel ? Ex. let users have a standard API to communicate with the remote server